# add a select dropdown on Contact Page

Tags: magento2, contact-us, contact-form

I'm looking for a way to be able to add a Dropdown (select) to the Contact Page and use it as a Subject later on in the email.

I've tried simply adding a dropdown but it doesn't seem to be working:

this is what I've tried in `form.phtml`

```
<div class="field subject required">
    <div class="control">
        <select id="subject" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
            <option value="Subject" disabled>Subject</option>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select> 
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the `Email Templates`

```
{{trans "Subject: %subject" subject=$data.subject}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the dropdown value cannot be passed to email template, but the input type do.

I use js to pass the value to input and make it working. It is not perfect but it is working. would like to know better solution.

in `Magento_Contact/templates/form.phtml`.

```
<div class="field enquiry">
<label class="label" for="enquiry"><span><?php echo __('Enquiry type?') ?></span></label>
<div class="control">
    <input name="enquiry" id="enquiry" title="<?php echo __('enquiry') ?>" value="Product Enquiry" class="input-text hide" type="text" />
    <select name="enquiry" id="enquiry_mirror">
        <option value="Product Enquiry" selected>Product Enquiry</option>
        <option value="Track my order">Track my order</option>
        <option value="other">other</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
<script>
require(['jquery'], function($){

  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#enquiry_mirror').change(function () {
          $('#enquiry').val($(this).val());
      });
  });

});
</script>
```

Then in email template

```
{{trans "Enquiry Type: %enquiry" enquiry=$data.enquiry}}
```